# HTTPPOST request calling with string parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, httpclient, webapi2

I have a POST request which have just a string parameter

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CheckMfaEnabled([FromBody]string userEmail)//
     {
         var isMfaEnabled = //use another service to return true/false
         return Ok(isMfaEnabled);
     }
```

and I call it like this

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60099");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userEmail), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = client.PostAsync("api/MFA/CheckMfaEnabled", content).Result;
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

It gets me **404 not found Error** , 
I guess something is wrong in my way of calling HTTPPOST.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a routing issue. When I modify your API method to use attribute routing by adding `[Route("api/MFA/CheckMfaEnabled")]` your client code works fine.